# Prevent select field from infinite scrolling (ng-select, angular)

Tags: angular, select, angular-ngselect

When using ng-select for select fields, if you get to scroll to the bottom (using the down arrow), the field goes all the way back up to the top (creating a loop).

For example, if I down arrow down to "TX, Dallas" and hit down again, it goes to the top.

Is there a way to disable this?

I'm trying to make this act like a normal select field where if you click down arrow on the last option, it stops (does not cycle back to the top)

```
<ng-select [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
</ng-select>

cities = [
    {id: 1, name: 'MA, Boston'},
    {id: 2, name: 'FL, Miami'},
    {id: 3, name: 'NY, New York'},
    {id: 4, name: 'CA, Los Angeles'},
    {id: 5, name: 'TX, Dallas'}
];
```

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-mbnngu